# Change values from inside the function

Tags: php

For learning reasons I created this small function, it just sorts values in array from small to large:

```
function mySort($list)
{  
    $number = count($list);

    for($i=0; $i<$number-1; $i++)
    {
        if($list[$i] > $list[$i + 1])
        {
            $temp = $list[$i];
            $list[$i] = $list[$i + 1];
            $list[$i + 1] = $temp;
            $i = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

How do you influence arrays outside of this function with it? Lets say I have `$a = [7,3,1,5,9];` and I just want to type `mySort($a);` and voila element positions in array will now be permanently changed.

Comment: Just create a variable and have a return statement? I.e `return $list` then thus would mean you should be able to do this: `$a = array(1, 2, 3, 4); $sorted = sort($a);`

Comment: Passing by reference is one way http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.php The other is returning from the function and reassigning the variable.

Comment: [Many of PHP's built-in array sorting functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php) accept an array reference as their argument.

Comment: Hah thank you Michael passing values by reference is the trick in these situations. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can [pass the argument by reference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php) to make the function modify the original array:

```
function mySort(&$list)
{  
    $number = count($list);

    for($i=0; $i<$number-1; $i++)
    {
        if($list[$i] > $list[$i + 1])
        {
            $temp = $list[$i];
            $list[$i] = $list[$i + 1];
            $list[$i + 1] = $temp;
            $i = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

[**Demo.**](https://eval.in/81044)

---

Alternatively, you could return the modified array, and store it in a variable, like so:

```
function mySort($list)
{  
    $number = count($list);

    for($i=0; $i<$number-1; $i++)
    {
        if($list[$i] > $list[$i + 1])
        {
            $temp = $list[$i];
            $list[$i] = $list[$i + 1];
            $list[$i + 1] = $temp;
            $i = 0;
        }
    }
    return $list;
}

$a = array(7,3,1,5,9);
$array = mySort($a);
print_r($array);
```

[**Demo.**](https://eval.in/81046)

Comment: And thank you too, references are new to me, I will study them. They do the trick!

Comment: @user3119695: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I'm glad to have been of help. :)